# HTML set input 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem here. I want to set the input tag to `width: 100%` inside another element  which `width: 100%`.

I tried to replace the input with a `div tag` and it worked. But I need it to be an `input tag`.

**My problem:** http://jsfiddle.net/HDtz3/483/

The input just "overflows". I want it to fill the whole blue div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a width to the input field and add float:left;
Same thing for the red container which will need an arbitrary width to allow the input field filling up the rest of the container width.

```
.red {
    width:5.5%;    
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}

input {    
    margin: 0;
    width:94.5%;
    padding: 0;   
    float:left;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Otherwise if you really cannot set a width you can use overflow:hidden on the blue container and then remove its width. This way the input will fill the rest of the container.

```
.red {
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

.blue {
    background: blue;
    overflow:hidden;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/HDtz3/496/

Comment: Why do you exactly need an input at 100% not occupying 100% of its container? Can I see your design layout?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that mean something like this:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/HDtz3/495/

[image]

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
    <div class="red">Label</div>

    <div class="blue">
    <input type="text" value="input"/>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.input-wrapper {display:table;width:100%;}
.input-wrapper > div {display:table-cell;padding:5px;}
.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.blue {
    background: blue;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    background:transparent;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Don't add floats to the divs inside the input-wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

This is the key:

```
display: inherit;
```

Together:

```
<style>
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.red {
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

.blue {
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
    display: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>

<div class="red">RED</div>
<div class="blue">
    <input type="text" value="kk"/>
</div>
```

Here is your updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/HDtz3/491/

Comment: @JackSparrow What browser do you using? Latest firefox is fine.

Comment: Using lastest chrome here! It doesn't work on IE too.